# wifi bridged to ethernet on a DIY router, not working

Tags: networking, wireless, dhcp, router, iwlwifi

I have a mini PC with dual nic and wifi setup to act as a router

my setup:

WAN port (enp2s0) -> cable modem

LAN port (enp3s0) -> gig switch

LAN and wifi are bridged to create "br0" which has a static IP of 10.1.10.1
mask 255.255.255.0
bcast 10.1.10.255
net 10.1.10.0

and br0 is assigned as the main adapter for DHCP to listen on

my wired PC can connect to the internet no problem! works great. DHCP server on the box assigns all the settings correctly.

I try to use hostapd to launch the wifi (sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf)... it acts as if it's working (reports AP-ENABLED and I see the network on wireless devices) but I can't connect -- either with WPA encryption on or off.

basically the device connects/disconnects over and over. never getting an IP address.

here's my TCP dump for the wifi adapter (wlp1s0) http://pastebin.com/ci24bfXP

here's my /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf http://pastebin.com/WTz1v3Qp

wifi device is "Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)" using iwlwifi

rfkill lists NO

tried killall wpa_supplicant

here's my dmesg dump after trying to launch the AP http://pastebin.com/q3VxpRUv

Answer (score 0):

seems it's just my phone, I just checked the dhcp clients list and my printer and chromecast seem to have zero problems. I just printed something over wifi.

one thing I will note, I made a minor change:

in /etc/network/interfaces I set the bridge (br0) to auto-start wifi and dhcp

```
iface br0 inet static
    post-up service hostapd start
    post-up service isc-dhcp-server restart
    address 10.1.10.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.1.10.255
    network 10.1.10.0
    dns-nameservers 10.1.10.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    dns-domain 10.1.10.1 magi.andsat.org
    bridge-ports enp3s0 wlp1s0
    post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```